# Mostrar el Top Bar al hacer scroll hacia arriba con sticky Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, foundation

Un efecto que me parece interesante y bastante util, es mostrar el menu cuando se escrolea hacia arriba, y ocultarlo cuando se va hacia abajo, si bien, hacia abajo facilmente puedo esconderlo con un `display: none`, usando la clase `is-stuck is-at-top`, de la funcion sticky de Foundation, sin embargo no se si esto se puede lograr de igual forma activandolo con un `display: block`, al scrolear hacia arriba, el menu mas o menos va asi

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><button class="hollow button border black-text" data-toggle="offCanvas"><i class="fi-list"></i></button></li>
        <li class="black-text"><%= link_to "Inicio", root_path, class: "bold" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu show-for-large">
        <li><%= link_to new_enterprise_registration_path, class: "button bold" do %><i class="fi-torsos-all"></i> Empresas<% end %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO** es posible lograr este efecto con las herramientas de Sticky en Foundation. Aún si pudieramos agregar un `is-at-bottom` al momento de hacer scroll hacia arriba y mostrar el menú, no habría forma de determinar posteriormente que se hace scroll hacia abajo para ocultar el menú. Simplemente sería muy complejo y corremos el riesgo de dañar el funcionamiento de Sticky.

Además, los únicos eventos que tiene Sticky son `stuckto` y `unstuckfrom`, no hay un punto medio en caso que estés en el medio de la página y hagas scroll hacia abajo y hacia arriba.

---

La solución sería sin duda alguna con Javascript puro o jQuery, algo así sería un punto de partida:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){  
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;  
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       document.getElementById("topmenu").style.top = "-100%";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("topmenu").style.top = "0";
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: honeydew;
}

#topmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: hotpink;  
}
```

```html
<div id=topmenu>
<span>top </span>
</div>

<div id=content>
<p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho la aclaración, y ha funcionado perfectamente! =D Saludos!